# Creating fixed size composite images with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have two images. One could be any size and aspect ratio.  The other is essentially a PNG mask of a patterned circle which I want to overlay over the other image, resizing the other image to fit the size of the PNG overlay.

I have the basics working with:

```
composite -compose atop -geometry +0+0 -resize 75x73 lib/source/overlay.png #{temp_object.path} #{tempfile.path}
```

However, this doesn't work if the source image's aspect ratio doesn't suit the overlay.  ImageMagicks resultant image crops the overlay to suit the source image.

So, how can I tweak this so that the source image is resized etc to fit within the overlay and my resultant image is always the same size and contains the full overlay?

Example Images:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to do what you want?

```
convert input.jpg -thumbnail 200x200^ -gravity center -crop 200x200+0+0 mask.png -composite output.jpg
```

Another method

```
composite input.jpg -thumbnail 200x200^ mask.png -gravity center -compose screen -matte output.jpg
```